# Woocommerce - Exclude variation attribute on specific variation

Tags: php, function, woocommerce, product-variations

I want to hide some attributes on specific variations.

I have the following attributes: Printing Position , Printing Technique , Print size, Colors.

You can see here https://ibb.co/qjV3Z75 that i have a variation with all attributes selected and a variation with all attributes selected except “Colors” because this variation doesn’t have “Colors”.

Is there a way to hide or remove attribute “Colors” from this variation? “Any Colors” would not work for me, because this variation doesn’t have “Colors” at all.

I’ve tried many conditional fields plugins but without success.

Aslo, i tried to hide attributes with a function based on this function

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', 'filter_dropdown_variation_args', 10, 1 ); function filter_dropdown_variation_args( $args ) {

// Remove colors attribute
foreach( $args['options'] as $key => $option ){
    if( $option === "LASER COMPASS" ) {
        unset // Colors;
    }
}
return $args;}
```

Comment: I'm looking to do something similar. Did you ever figure this out by chance?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I've tried many things but I'm sure that it needs javascript to work and I din't try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating additional attribute value "No color" for Colors attribute could do the trick.

For the mentioned combination of "LASER COMPASS", "Laser engraving ( L2 ) - Max..." and "27" would be created only one variation with the option "No color" which would be automatically pre-selected after selecting that specific combination of mentioned attribute values.

I suppose this can't be done on the backend (PHP), so the frontend solution could look like this - on Single product page (JS+jQuery):

```
jQuery(($) => {
    const printingPositionSelect = 'attribute_pa_printing-position';
    const printingTechniqueSelect = 'attribute_pa_printing-technique';
    const printSizeSelect = 'attribute_pa_print-size';
    const colorsSelect = 'attribute_pa_colors';
    const noColorValue = 'no-color';

    // Function to update the variation selection
    const updateVariationSelection = () => {
        const selectedPrintingPosition = $('select[name="' + printingPositionSelect + '"]').val();
        const selectedPrintingTechnique = $('select[name="' + printingTechniqueSelect + '"]').val();
        const selectedPrintSize = $('select[name="' + printSizeSelect + '"]').val();

        if (selectedPrintingPosition === 'laser-compass' && selectedPrintingTechnique === "le-l2-max" && selectedPrintSize === "27") {
            $('select[name="' + colorsSelect + '"]').val(noColorValue);
            $('select[name="' + colorsSelect + '"]').parents("tr").hide();
        } else {
            $('select[name="' + colorsSelect + '"]').val('');
            $('select[name="' + colorsSelect + '"]').parents("tr").show();
        }
    }

    // Initial update on page load
    updateVariationSelection();

    // Bind the change event to the selects to keep updating when the user changes options
    $('select').on('change', () => {
        updateVariationSelection();
    });
});
```

It must be mentioned that if you don't want to show the attribute value "No color" for customers, it must be hidden on other pages where the product attributes are visible, e.g. Cart, Checkout, My Account -> Orders and even in WooCommerce e-mails and invoices. All of this can be done, but specific actions like this usually require a great deal of patience.

The solution above could work for a couple of pre-defined specific combinations of attribute values (which use "No color"), but if you know these specific combinations will eventually rise, creating a universal JSON file and defining combinations inside it would be better. The pages (Cart, Checkout, ...) can then fetch the JSON file and hide the attribute(-s) based on what the JSON file contains. I said "universal" JSON file, because you would then only need to change the JSON file content (add/remove combinations) rather than changing JS code on each page and writing repetitive code.